# ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 when trying to sign in using next-auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, next.js, next-auth

I use [next-auth.js](https://next-auth.js.org/) library to create authentication system for Next.js my application.
Everything works fine on my local computer, but after deploying website to [Vercel](https://vercel.com/), my sign in function doesn't work.

The sign in page `(/pages/signin)` loads fine, i submit credentials and i get an error like this:
`https://projectname-git-branch.username.now.sh/api/auth/error?error=Error%3A%20connect%20ECONNREFUSED%20127.0.0.1%3A80`.

I found many articles that error is about to wrong `baseURL` configured for `axios`, but i have many `axios` requests everywhere in code (for example i get data from firebase after app loads) and it works without any problem.

I console logged environment variable where i set `baseURL` property for `axios` and it's fine.

```js
// _app.js
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.FIREBASE_APIURL;
console.log('axios-baseurl', axios.defaults.baseURL) // it prints right url
```

More informations about this problem i wrote there: [#846](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/846)

I really don't know what to do. I don't get any information about where this error happens, which file and line number, what request in my code.

Below i put my whole `[...nextauth.js]` file and sign in form. Maybe there is something what i should to configure better there.

```js
// [...nextauth.js]
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers'

import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.FIREBASE_APIURL;
console.log('axios-baseurl', axios.defaults.baseURL)

const sha1 = require('crypto-js/sha1');
const md5 = require('crypto-js/md5');

export default (req, res) => 
    NextAuth(req, res, {
        providers: [
            Providers.Credentials({
                name: 'Credentials',
                credentials: {
                    phone: { label: "Numer telefonu", type: "text" },
                    password: { label: "Haslo", type: "password" }
                },
                authorize: async (loginData) => {
                    const { csrfToken, phone, password } = loginData;
                    
                    //  checking if there is account with these credentials
                    let res = await login({
                        phone, 
                        password: sha1(md5(password)).toString()
                    })

                    //  200 = OK
                    if(res.status == 200){
                        //  check if account was activated
                        if(res.data.info.activated == "true"){
                            //  collect account data
                            const user = {
                                phone,
                                ...res.data.info
                            }
                            return Promise.resolve(user);
                        }
                        else{
                            //  account is not activated by sms code
                            return Promise.reject(new Error("AccountNotActivated"));
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        //  wrong credentials
                        return Promise.reject(new Error("WrongCredentials"));
                    }
                }
            })
        ],
        callbacks: {
            jwt: async (token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) => {
                user && (token.user = user);
                return Promise.resolve(token)
            },
            session: async (session, user, sessionToken) => {
                session.user = user.user;
                return Promise.resolve(session)
            }
        },
        
        pages: {
            signIn: '/signin'
        },
        
        site: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL || "localhost:3000",
        debug: true
    })


//  function which sends login request to rest api and returns result
//  https://stackoverflow.com/q/64244115
const login = async data => await axios.post('/checkCredentials', data);
```

```html
<!-- /pages/signin.js -->
<form action="/api/auth/callback/credentials" method="post">
    <input name='csrfToken' type='hidden' defaultValue={csrfToken} />
    <label>
        Numer telefonu: <br />
        <input name='phone' type='text' required autoComplete='off' />
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>
        Hasło: <br />
        <input name='password' type='password' required autoComplete='off' />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj" />
</form>
```

Comment: I have similar issue... what a pain .. lol, did you manage to find a solution? I read many post and didn't find anything :( thanks

Comment: Any update on that ? Similar issue here.. Thanks !

Comment: @Romaixn Did you properly setup `NEXTAUTH_URL` environment variables with the right value (prod URL) in Vercel?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set environment variables for production use:

NEXTAUTH_URL (e.g. NEXTAUTH_URL='https://example.com'

https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#nextauth_url

**and**

NEXTAUTH_SECRET (e.g. NEXTAUTH_SECRET='MYGENERATEDOPENSSLSECRET')

documentation @ https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#nextauth_secret

You can generate a secret on the command line (only one possible way)

```
openssl rand -base64 32
```

Add both variables to your vercel deployment:
https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables